# How to send an email in PHP reliably?

Tags: php, email

i am learning how to send an email.i have installed appserver and in files 
php.ini-dist and php.ini-recommended i did the following changes

```
SMTP=localhost

sendmail_from=me@localhost.com
```

i replaced localhost with mail.ptcl.net which is my dsl provider 
and replaced me@localhost.com with my email address h_k9@live.com

i get the following message when i submit the form

> "warning: mail() [function.mail]:
>   "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or
>   custom "From:" header missing in
>   C:\AppServ\www\Hamza\send_simpleform.php
>   on line 14 The following e-mail has
>   been sent:
>
> Hamza: hamza
>
> h_k9@live.com
>
> Message: adasdas"

following is the script i am using

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Feedback Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="send_simpleform.php"/>
<p><strong>Your name</strong><br/>
<input type="text" name="sender_name" size="30" /></p>
<p><strong>Senders Email address</strong><br/>
<input type="text" name="sender_email" size="30" /></p>
<p><strong>Enter your Message here</strong><br/>
<textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="5" wrap="virtual"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="send this form" name="submit"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
if(($_POST[sender_name]=="")||($_POST[sender_email]="")||($_POST[message==""]                                                                                                          ))
{   header("location=simple_form.html");
    exit;
}
$msg="E-MAIL SENT FROM WWW SITE\n";
$msg="Sender's Name:  $_POST[sender_name]\n";
$msg="Sender's E-Mal I.D:    $_POST[sender_email]\n";
$msg="Message:                 $_POST[message]\n";
$to="h_k9@live.com";
$subject="Web site feedback";
$mailholders="from my website<geriadress@yourdomain.com>\n";
$mailheader="Reply-to: $_POST[sender_email]\n";
mail($to, $subject,$msg,$mailheaders);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Feedback Form Sent</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The following e-mail has been sent:</h1>
<p><strong>Hamza:</strong><br\>
<?php echo "$_POST[sender_name]";?>
<p><strong>h_k9@live.com</strong><br\>
<?php echo "$_POST[sender_email]";?>
<p><strong>Message:</strong><br>
<? echo "$_POST[message]";?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the error message not helpful to you in any way?

Comment: @Silent, we where all new at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have at least two problems:

1. I am guessing that `php.ini-recommended` and `php.ini-dist` are respectively an example and a template configuration files; modifications to them may not impact the "real" `php.ini`, currently used by your instance of PHP. Use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to make sure that your configuration is correct.
2. Spam filters. Jeff Atwood has a pretty good [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) about implementing the checks that servers do when checking if your email message is spammy. Don't forget:

> Just because you *send* an email doesn't mean it will arrive.

Comment: when i send an email wont i receive it in my email address h_k9@live.com?

Comment: @rookie Assuming that things are configured correctly and that the email isn't blocked by a spam filter.

Answer (score 1):

As jhominal points out, the php.ini files you've modified are just examples.  You'll have to find out where the php.ini is for your distribution and modify it.

As mentioned by others, you can set a custom from header.  However, if you don't set sendmail_from in php.ini you'll have to remember to always set it.

At any rate, here is a pretty good article/tutorial on sending email with PHP's mail() function:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/advanced-email-php

Answer (score 0):

It could be simplier to use an external library to send mails, as http://swiftmailer.org/ instead of playing with php.ini

It's never good to be php.ini dependant.

Comment: `It's never good to be php.ini dependant.`  What's that supposed to mean?  You're pretty much always dependent on php.ini.  Not all configuration options are available for runtime modification.  Meanwhile, a mail library is a good idea, as they are easier to use than the `mail()` function.  However, if things aren't configured correctly, they don't do jack for you.

Comment: I mean sometimes you have to deploy scripts or sites on several servers, and it can happens you have not the possibility to modify php.ini. It's why I don't like to have scripts too much dependant on that.

Comment: That's a fair point, which I believe should be made more obvious in your statement.  You do allude to that by stating `instead of playing with php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  This worked for me in my site.

```
$email = "your e-mail address";
$myname = "name";
$mymail = "reply Address";
    $subject = "SUBJECT LINE";
    $body = "TEXT GOES HERE";
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\nFrom: $myname <$mymail>\n
    Reply-To: <$mymail>\nBCC:<$mymail>\nReturn-Path: <$mymail>\nX-Mailer: PHP";

            //send the email
            if ($email != "") { 
                mail($email,$subject,$body,$headers); 
            }
```

Comment: @SilentGhost - I know that seems like a cop out to say that, but...  It did.  I don't remember changing anything in the php.ini file so maybe, he is just missing something in his script that mine isn't.  At least it is something.

Comment: The issue is that the OP's error message points to an issue with the "from" email header.  What you've posted is a total shot in the dark which ignores that important bit and it doesn't set the from header, so it would need to correctly set in php.ini.

Comment: I was thinking it was the Content_Type: and the Reply-To: syntax as I remember it was very finicky.  I was looking at it from the low hanging fruit side rather than having to dive into the php.ini.

Comment: Upon further review, it does set the From header.  /facepalm