# email send request to user

Tags: php

i want to create a button and one text box. now i want user can send any site of link to his friend how can i give this all. can i get any structure of code or can i get code that where i can create this.

Comment: You'll need two text boxes - one for the email address, and one for the site link... Your question seems vague... are you asking just about how to send an email with php? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297531/how-to-send-an-email-in-php-reliably

Comment: more i am developing one site in there have need to user can send request to other also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use something like [PHP mailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) on your site then you can integrate that into the mailing and make things really easy for yourself.  Just add in the settings, build the e-mail and pass it through the functions that are needed.

Comment: ok 
but can i get some idea to get code

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<label for="email">your friend email</label>
<input name="email" type="edit"/>
<input type="submit" value="send link to friend"/>
</form>
<?
if (isset($_POST('email')) {
  if (!mail($_POST('email'), "Site link", "check this link " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    echo "I couldn't send email, sorry.";
  }
}

?>
```